# Builder pattern respecting the open-close principle

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns, builder

I have the following code:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        # address
        street = None
        post_code = None
        city = None
        # empoyment
        company_name = None
        position = None


class PersonBuilder:

    def __init__(self, person=Person()):
        self.person = person

    def build(self):
        return self.person

    @property
    def works(self):
        return PersonJobBuilder(self.person)

    @property
    def lives(self):
        return PersonAddressBuilder(self.person)


class PersonJobBuilder(PersonBuilder):

    def __init__(self, person):
        super().__init__(person)

    def at(self, company):
        self.person.company_name = company
        return self


class PersonAddressBuilder(PersonBuilder):

    def __init__(self, person):
        super().__init__()

    def city(self, city):
        self.person.city = city
        return self

pb = PersonBuilder()

person = pb\
    .works \
        .at('Cora')\
    .lives \
        .city('Kandu')\
    .build()
```

The code above is not respecting the open-close principle, because everytime I want to add a new builder I need to change the `PersonBuilder` class to add methods like `lives`, `works`.

I know that inheritance can be used, but doesn't make sense for `PersonAddressBuilder` to inherit from `PersonJobBuilder`.

So, what other solutions are available?

Comment: Please expand on why you think this isn’t providing the open-closed principle. What you’ve said in the question doesn’t square with either of the popular definitions of the open-closed principle as far as I can tell.

Comment: Why can't you extend the existing class in a subclass and add the methods that way?

Comment: @ChrisJohnson; if I add a new builder, let's say "PersonPlayBuilder", I have to change the "PersonBuilder" to add the function "play" that returns an instance of "PersonPlay Builder"; to respect the "close" principle I shouldn't need to change the "PersonBuilder" every time I need to add a new builder.

Comment: @martineau I didn't said I can't do it, I said it doesn't make sense. Off course I can do PersonAddressBuilder(PersonJobBuilder) and call the builder in the main class, but location address is not directly connected to job, it is not logic in my opinion to do that.

Comment: I understand what you’re trying to do, but that’s not about the open-closed principle. You can add new fields and methods: that means it is in fact open. Now you’re debating the best / most convenient way to do that, fair enough. I’ll respond in that sense separately.

Answer (score 0):

One typical way to reduce dependencies between classes is to not use inheritance but instead use a mixin model.

That approach aligns strongly with the duck-typed approach you favor, at the cost of having to ensure field and method names are not repeated across mixins — not an issue when the scope is narrow; sometimes an issue when you are designing mixins for reuse by disparate classes.